# How to get p-value and pearson's r for a list of columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, correlation

I'm trying to make a multiindexed table (a matrix) of correlation coefficients **and** p-values. I'd prefer to use the `scipy.stats` tests.

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        zip(
            [1,2,3,4,5,6], [5, 7, 8, 4, 2, 8], [13, 16, 12, 11, 9, 10]
            )
            ),
            columns= ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
            )
 

# I've tried something like this
for i in range(len(x.columns)):
    r,p = pearsonr(x[x.columns[i]], x[x.columns[i+1]])
    print(f'{r}, {p}')
```

Obviously the `for loop` won't work. What I want to end up with is:

|  |  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | r | 1.0 | -.09 | -.8 |
|  | p | .00 | .87 | .06 |
| b | r | -.09 | 1 | .42 |
|  | p | .87 | .00 | .41 |
| c | r | -.8 | .42 | 1 |
|  | p | .06 | .41 | 00 |

I had written code to solve this problem (with help from this community) years ago, but it only worked for an older version of `spearmanr`.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using scipy [pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) and Pandas [corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) methods:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def pearsonr_pval(x, y):
    return pearsonr(x, y)[1]


df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            x.corr(method="pearson").reset_index().assign(value="r"),
            x.corr(method=pearsonr_pval).reset_index().assign(value="p"),
        ]
    )
    .groupby(["index", "value"])
    .agg(lambda x: list(x)[0])
).sort_index(ascending=[True, False])

df.index.names = ["", ""]
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
            a         b         c

a r  1.000000 -0.088273 -0.796421
  p  1.000000  0.867934  0.057948
b r -0.088273  1.000000  0.421184
  p  0.867934  1.000000  0.405583
c r -0.796421  0.421184  1.000000
  p  0.057948  0.405583  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I'm trying to write some functions that will return python output in a style that is more familliar to SPSS users to help them learn python, you're a hero.

Comment: How would I edit this code so that the index is in the same order as the columns?

Comment: Hi, adding `.reindex(labels=x.columns, level=0)` after the first `sort_index` should do the trick. Cheers.